# Overriding ArrayList

Tags: android

I' ve created an ArrayList list1 and an ArrayListArrayList> final_list. list1 includes information about one single customer and final_list for many customers. I provide the nessesary code segment for simplicity.

```
public class CheckItineraries extends FragmentActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String username, origin_lat, origin_lng, destination_lat, destination_lng,
        waypoint1_lat, waypoint1_lng, waypoint2_lat, waypoint2_lng,
        waypoints;
int i, j, b;
TextView v1, v2;
String start_pro , final_pro;

double z = 0;
ListView list;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
ArrayList<Double> sum = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> differ = new ArrayList<Double>();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  final_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/check_itineraries.php";

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

// JSON Node names

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itinList;

ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> final_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkitineraries);

    itinList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new GetData().execute();
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("meg", "meg");

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckItineraries.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Επεξεργάζομαι τα στοιχεία...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        username = settings.getString("username", "nikos");

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray itin_results = json.getJSONArray("itin_results");

            for (int i = 0; i < itin_results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = itin_results.getJSONObject(i);

                String username = c.getString("username");
                String startPoliPro = c.getString("startPoliPro");
                String start_lat_pro = c.getString("start_lat_pro");
                String start_lng_pro = c.getString("start_lng_pro");
                String finalPoliPro = c.getString("finalPoliPro");
                String final_lat_pro = c.getString("final_lat_pro");
                String final_lng_pro = c.getString("final_lng_pro");

                list1.add(username);
                list1.add(startPoliPro);
                list1.add(finalPoliPro);

                final_list.add(i, list1);

                Log.d("list1",list1.toString());

                Log.d("final_list", final_list.toString());

                list1.clear();
```

The problem is that second list1 entries to final_list overrides the first one.

LogCat

```
10-04 15:46:22.249: D/list1(25850): [p, Athens, Halkida]
10-04 15:46:22.249: D/final_list(25850): [[p, Athens, Halkida]]
10-04 15:46:22.249: D/list1(25850): [e, Athens, Larissa]
10-04 15:46:22.249: D/final_list(25850): [[e, Athens, Larissa], [e, Athens, Larissa]]
```

I know its elementary but i appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't declare `ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();` at the class level, the problem is the reference is added (not a deep copy). Instead, declare it in the `for()` loop -

```
for (int i = 0; i < itin_results.length(); i++) {
  List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- Use the interface and Java 7+  
                                          //     can use diamond operator
  JSONObject c = itin_results.getJSONObject(i);
  // ...
  // list1.clear(); // <-- didn't work because of shallow copy.
}
```

**Or**, use a deep copy by changing from

```
final_list.add(i, list1);
```

to

```
final_list.add(i, new ArrayList<>(list1)); // <-- Diamond Operator
```